# Attempting to convert json into csv with tempfile and receiving a "no such file or directory" error

Tags: python

I'm attempting to convert JSON data into a csv with tempfile and am receiving a "no such file or directory" error.

```
testjson = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}

def sso():
    # Add SQL Here
    # Creates a temp dir
    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    path = os.path.join(tempdir)
    with open(path + '/temp.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(testjson, fp)


    # Changes the data to CSV
    def json_to_csv(path, fileInput, fileOutput):
        inputFile = open(path + fileInput)
        data = json.load(inputFile)
        inputFile.close()
        with open(os.path.join(path, fileOutput), 'w') as fp:
            output = csv.writer(fp)
            output.writerow(data[0].keys())
            for row in data:
                output.writerow(row.values())

    json_to_csv(path, '/testjson.json', '/xxx.csv')
```

The full errors are:
line 47, in sso json_to_csv(path, '/testjson.json', '/xxx.csv')

line 38, in json_to_csv inputFile = open(path + fileInput)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\CHRIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8mc6dxup/testjson.json'

To be perfectly honest, I am quite new to programming and python. I found these code blocks from an article that neatly described exactly what I need to do. (Take Json, convert to csv, and email it through lambda.) I would be so grateful for any insight.

Comment: The problem seems to be that you are creating "temp.json" but are attempting to read from "testjson.json".  You should make those the same name.

Comment: `join` takes care of the slashes for you. Ex: `path = os.path.join(tempdir, 'temp.json')`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp has a good point, but remember that doing `path + fileInput` does NOT automatically add the slash.  You might consider using `os.path.join` there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `os.path.join()` when merging pathnames, so the interpreter doesn't get confused about mismatched path separators.

```
testjson = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}

def sso():

    tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    path = os.path.join(tempdir, 'temp.json')
    with open(path, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(testjson, fp)


    # Changes the data to CSV
    def json_to_csv(path, fileInput, fileOutput):
        data = json.load(open(os.path.join(path, fileInput)))
        with open(os.path.join(path, fileOutput), 'w') as fp:
            output = csv.writer(fp)
            output.writerow(data[0].keys())
            for row in data:
                output.writerow(row.values())

    json_to_csv(tempdir, 'testjson.json', 'xxx.csv')
```

Comment: So that yeilds about the same result: line 24, in json_to_csv
    data = json.load(open(os.path.join(path, fileInput)))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\CHRIST~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpgo38ylgy\\testjson.json'

Comment: @ChristineM  Your welcom.